# Creating a query to insert data into MySQL using foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I am a total newbie at DB's and I'm trying to insert data into the following tables:

> Table Start

Table = users

Columns = id , username , password

Table = users_info

Columns = id , e-mail , address , logged , portrait , user_id

> Table End

users_info.user_id is a foreign key linked to users.id.

I want to build a query that will insert data into (users_info table) based on information from (users table)... literal i.e.:

```
Insert portrait into users_info where user_id = users.id and username = JohnDoe
```

What is the syntax to get this going?

Thanks!!

Comment: No I want to insert data into users_info on the row that matches the user_id = users.id. This is not for creating a new entry or row, but to update an existing one. Yes the id column on both tables are primary keys on AUTO_INCREMENT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to do is update the data in `users_info` table then you have to use the UPDATE command.

```
UPDATE users_info a SET a.portrait = 'value1', a.logged = 'value2', a.address = 'value3', a.email = 'value4' where a.user_id = (SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM users b WHERE b.username = 'JohnDoe')
```

Basics on SQL commands on http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Good Luck!

Comment: Awesome that worked perfectly, thanks LoBS. ALso thank you for the SQL tutorial link, I really do need it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Insert portrait into users_info 
(id, email) VALUES ( select user.id, 'johndoe@domain.com' )
where user_id = users.id and username = 'JohnDoe'
)
```